# I cant put a background-image

Tags: html, sass

Im doing a website (is not my fist page) but in this I cant put a image for background. Is not the first time that i do that so i cant no explain me why I cant do it in this time.

Im working with SASS and HTML5, this is my code:

HTML

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="contenedor contenido-header">
            <h1>Hola!<br> Soy <span>name,</span> <br> profesionn</h1>
            <h2>Te invito a ver algunos de los proyectos que he creado</h2>

            <nav class="navegacion">
                <a href="#">CV</a>
                <a href="#">Habilidades</a>
                <a href="#">Sobre Mí</a>
                <a href="#">Contacto</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

SCSS

```
.header {
    //background-color: $rosa;
    background-image: url(../../img/header.jpg); -->This is my problem
    padding: 8rem 0 6rem 0;

    .contenido-header {
        text-align: center;

        h2 {
            margin-top: 3rem;
        }
        span {
            color: $dorado;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check if path is right ? url(../../img/header.jpg); OR url(../img/header.jpg); Or try with full path like url(https://www.domainxx.com/img/header.jpg);

Comment: Thanks! It was the path

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the quatations ", make sure that surround url with quatation mark.

```css
background-image: url("../../img/header.jpg");
```